# Automatically resize an object by a percentage when a particular object style is applied to it

Tags: adobe-indesign, eps, script, javascript

I work for an education company, and we deal with a good number of fractions when writing our publications. We currently use MathType to generate the fractions, which saves each fraction as a separate .eps file so we can place them into InDesign.

However, the fractions generated by MathType are 100% of the font we set within MathType, and we'd like for them to be scaled down a bit...say to 85% of the "base" font size.

Is there any way we can have InDesign scale down these fractions by a percentage?

Not all of the equations brought in by MathType are fractions, so we'd need a way to target just the fractions. One idea I had while writing this was to tag each of the fractions with the object style of "fraction," and then use a script to sniff out all of these and change the size by 85%. Any direction on where to go for a method like this (or another that might work) is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just scale the places .eps files to 85%?? They'll be listed in the **Links** panel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I suppose I could, but in one document for instance, we might have 300 fractions. I'd prefer something more automated for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippet you can run as a script:

```
#target indesign

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var myObjectStyle = doc.objectStyles.itemByName("fractionStyle");
var myScaleFactor = 85;

for(var i = 0; i < doc.pageItems.length; i++){

if(doc.pageItems[i].appliedObjectStyle == myObjectStyle){
    doc.pageItems[i].horizontalScale = doc.pageItems[i].verticalScale = myScaleFactor;
    }
}
```

This will loop through all page items in the document, look for the ones that have the object Style "fractionStyle" assigned to them and scale them to 85% of their original size.

Remember to set the reference point for transformations first (upper left corner) to control in which direction the scaling will happen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the **"Find and replace"** window in Indesign (cmd+f):
   [image]
2. Click on "find format"
3. Insert the info of the type you want to change, be as specific as possible: font, size, colour, weight, etc.
4. Go to "change format"
5. Insert your new font size
6. Click at change all
   **If you are not sure your parameters are specific enough you can easily change them one by one by clicking change/find

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately these files are .eps vector files, so the font isn't editable unless I open each one up in Illustrator and change the font there, but that would take too long.

Comment: The same can be done with objects, just move to the object tab

Comment: Even if you use the object tab, how would you go about the scaling then?
Since the object format cannot scale an object (or can it?), the Find/Change dialog is not much of a help here, I think.
Or am I missing something?